# How to calculate an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptography

I need to find an elliptic curve in $F_{19}$ that has $|E(F_{19})|=18$. I am really stuck here. Can anyone help?

Comment: $F_{19}$ or $F_1 9$

Comment: F_{19} of course

Comment: you say of course..but there was an edit that said the latter. So I was making sure.

Comment: You should tell us what you have tried. In general we don't like to spoon-feed answers to people wo hasn't shown any effort.

Comment: It is possible that there is a generic recipe for a curve with $p-1$ points, but I don't remember one (or rather, I remember how to get $p+1$ only). Simple testing shows that
$$E:y^2=x^3+x+6$$ works. HOLD ON A SEC. Searching... Nope, wrong recollection.

Comment: Ok I have tried using PARI/GP and guessing points (x,y) that have square root of y. Tried to somehow connect the fact that its $|E(F_p)|=p+1+\sum\limits{x\in F_p}(f(x)/p)$

Comment: If you try finding all elliptic curves with nonzero discriminant and check if its order is 18 sooner or later you'll find one that fits, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for curves of the form $y^2=x^3+x+k$ gave me the following hit. With $k=6$, the value of $f(x)=x^3+x+6$ is zero for $x=6$ (1 point), and $f(x)$ is a non-zero square of $\Bbb{F}_{19}$ for eight choices $x=0,2,3,4,10,12,14,18$ (16 points). Including the point at infinity gives us a total of 18 points.

---

The Mathematica snippet

```
counter = 1; For[y = 0, y < 19, ++y, t = Mod[y^2, 19];
 For[x = 0, x < 19, ++x, 
  If[Mod[x^3 + x + 6, 19] == t, ++counter]]]; counter
```

was used. No need to do anything fancier than a brute force double loop with such a small field.

Comment: $k=7$ works equally well. Not much to it. Parity considerations force us to use cubics with an odd number of zeros on the r.h.s.

Comment: If you stumble upon a curve with 22 points instead of 18, you can apply [this trick](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1089617/11619) that "reflects" the number of points about the value $p+1=20$.