# Number of points of elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 - x$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ with $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Let $p$ be a prime number with $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$, and consider the elliptic curve
$$
E/\mathbb{F}_{p^2}: \quad y^2 = x^3 - x.
$$
I suspect that $E(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})$ has order $(p+1)^2$ as I observed it with MAGMA (the code I used can be found below).

I found a similar-looking argument in [Jyrki Lahtonen's answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/319847) (where he dealt with the same curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$ instead of $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$). It seems that the crucial argument there was that $-1$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$. However, I think $-1$ will become a square in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, so the argument fails I think.

> **Question** How can I show my claim instead?

**Appendix**: My MAGMA code (Output gives only "true").

```
L := [ x : x in [3 .. 100] | IsPrime(x) and x mod 4 eq 3];

for p in L do
    K := GF(p^2);
    R<x> := PolynomialRing(K);
    f := x^3 - x;
    E := EllipticCurve(f);
    #E eq (p+1)^2;
end for;
```

Comment: It gets much easier when learning the norm, trace and minimal polynomial of Frobenius stuffs. Follow Silverman AEC.

Comment: The theory of zeta functions of curves over finite fields tells you the following. If $E$ is an elliptic curve defined over $\Bbb{F}_p$, and $N=N_1=\# E(\Bbb{F}_p)$, then we can find complex numbers $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2=\overline{\omega_1}$ such that
$$N=p+1-\omega_1-\omega_2,$$
$$|\omega_1|=|\omega_2|=\sqrt p.$$
Furthermore (Hasse-Davenport), the number of points $N_m$ on $E$ that are rational over $\Bbb{F}_{p^m}$ is then given by
$$N_m=p^m+1-\omega_1^m-\omega_2^m.$$ 
With this curve $E$ the information about $N_1$ allows us to deduce that $\omega_{1,2}=\pm i\sqrt{p}$.

Comment: (cont'd) Therefore the number of points of $y^2=x^3-x$ over $\Bbb{F}_{p^m}$ is
$$N_m=p^m+1-(i\sqrt p)^m-(-i\sqrt p)^m.$$
Plugging in $m=2$ gives
$$N_2=p^2+1+p+p=(p+1)^2.$$

Comment: What this means is that for any elliptic curve defined over the prime field knowing $N_1$ gives you $N_m$ for all $m$. The same piece of information can be coded into a recurrence relation satisfied by $N_i$, $i=1,2,\ldots$, but I am used to going via the route of finding the $\omega$s. Similar technique is available for smooth higher genus $g>1$ curves also. The number of $\omega$s is equal to $2g$. You then need to find $N_1,N_2,\ldots, N_g$ to determine the values of the $\omega$s, and then get the rest of the $N_i$s.

Comment: (cont'd) The $\omega$s come in complex conjugate pairs. And the (proven) Riemann hypothesis for function fields states that $|\omega_i|=p^{1/2}$ for all $i$.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029499/number-of-points-on-the-elliptic-curve-y2-x3-x-over-mathbbf-q)

Comment: Great recollection @ViktorVaughn. I can leave this to your able hands (and brain) :-)

Answer (score 2):

For $\mathbb{F}_p$, the argument is that $$\#E(\mathbb{F}_p) = 1 + \sum_{x\in \mathbb{F}_p} \left(1+{{\genfrac{(}{)}{}{}{x^3-x}{p}}}\right)$$

Since $x^3-x$ is an odd function, and $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, it follows that ${{\genfrac{(}{)}{}{}{x^3-x}{p}}}$ is also an odd function, so
$$\sum_{x\in \mathbb{F}_p} {{\genfrac{(}{)}{}{}{x^3-x}{p}}} = 0$$
which implies $\#E(\mathbb{F}_p) = p+1.$

For $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$, the easiest way to see that $\#E(\mathbb{F}_{p^2}) = (p+1)^2$ is to take the complex multiplication endomorphism $\phi\colon E \to E$ sending $(x,y)$ to $(-x,y\cdot \sqrt{-1})$. From standard theory,
$$\#E(\mathbb{F}_p) = \deg(1-\pi)$$

$$\#E(\mathbb{F}_{p^2}) = \deg(1-\pi^2)$$
where $\pi$ denotes the $p$-th power Frobenius map. But $1-\pi^2 = (1-\pi)(1+\pi)$, and $\deg(1+\pi) = \#E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ because $1+\pi$ is separable and the kernel of $1+\pi$ is equal to the image of $E(\mathbb{F}_p)$ under $\phi$, so
$$\deg(1-\pi^2) = \deg(1-\pi)\deg(1+\pi) = (p+1)^2.$$

For a general elliptic curve $E: y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ and $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, a version of this argument still works. The map $\phi$ as defined above maps from $E$ to $E' : y^2 = x^3 + ax - b$ and we have
$\#E'(\mathbb{F}_p) = p+1+t$ where $t$ is the trace of $E/\mathbb{F}_p$, so we obtain
$$\#E(\mathbb{F}_{p^2}) = (p+1-t)(p+1+t).$$
Alternatively, the proof of rationality of the zeta function for $E$ immediately gives you the above formula in full generality, as well as formulas for $\#E(\mathbb{F}_{p^k})$ for all $k$.